# How to get specific data from a html file in JAVA

Tags: java, html

I've a html file that contains 2k+ lines of code that looks like this :

```
< tr>
  <td class="name">Abkhazia</td>
  <td>Asia<br>
    <small>(Central West)</small>
  </td>

  <td>Sukhumi</td>
  <td>Georgian lari;<br>Russian ruble</td>

  <td class="numeric">216,000</td>
  <td class="numeric">8,600</td>
  <td class="numeric">25</td>
  <td class="numeric">-</td>
  <td class="numeric">-</td>
  <td class="numeric">-</td>
  <td class="numeric">-</td>
< /tr>
```

I need extract following data from it:
`Country_Name`, `Capital_City`, `Population`, `which are 1'st`, `3'rd` and `5'th` `<td> content < /td>` on the list , for each next Country.

How to do that? I tried many ideas, for example with Jsoup :

```
public static String html2text(String html) {
  return Jsoup.parse(html).text();
}
```

But that seems not enough while `< td> Location < /td>` which is 2'nd on the list or Currency (same issue 4'th on the list) may contain more than one word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code snippet uses Jsoup to extract tags (taken from [Extract Tags from a html file using Jsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25929112/extract-tags-from-a-html-file-using-jsoup)):

```
public class JsoupDepthFirst {

    private static String htmlTags(Document doc) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        htmlTags(doc.children(), sb);
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private static void htmlTags(Elements elements, StringBuilder sb) {
        for(Element el:elements) {
            if(sb.length() > 0){
                sb.append(",");
            }
            sb.append(el.nodeName());
            htmlTags(el.children(), sb);
            sb.append(",").append(el.nodeName());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args){
        String s = "<html><head>this is head </head><body>this is body</body></html>";
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(s);
        System.out.println(htmlTags(doc));
    }
}
```